# How to convert JSON object to file and then response it using ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an pretty large JSON object (~500MB) and i want to convert it to file before send it to user. What is the best way to achieve this using ExpressJS, any suggestion would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***1- Convert json to string***

```
 var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

***2- Use fs to write json on file***

```
 var fs = require('fs');
 fs.writeFile('fileName.json', json, 'utf8', callback);
```